# JS Scroll event efficiency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

Hi everyone I would like to know when my user has scroll bellow 220px. I've created a event who trigger correctly my useState when the user scrolled below 220px

```js
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {

    if (this.window.scrollY > 200 && isScroll === false) {
      console.log("bon");
      setIsScroll(true);
    } else if (this.window.scrollY < 200 && isScroll === true) {
      console.log("fini");
      setIsScroll(false);
    }
  });
```

my question is: Is their a better way to do it because when I scrool only a little I've got a lot of instruction. And Will it be a problem on my application efficiency?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAJOR performance issue due to the event listener not being wrapped in a useEffect with a remove event listener as the return.

You're just piling up event listeners every time the component rerenders. Which is why you're seeing tens of thousands of console.logs after just a few scrolls.

```
  const [isScroll, setIsScroll] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 200 && isScroll === false) {
        console.log("bon");
        setIsScroll(true);
      } else if (window.scrollY < 200 && isScroll === true) {
        console.log("fini");
        setIsScroll(false);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, { passive: true });
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [isScroll]);
```

Above solution solves this problem. Note the **isScroll** parameter being passed to the useEffect dependency array in order to update the **handleScroll** function with the current state.